# How to catch an exception and email information about it in liferay portlet

Tags: exception, spring-mvc, portlet, liferay

I have a custom portlet made for liferay and sometimes it throws an exception. Why it throws exceptions is irrelevant.

How to catch exceptions thrown by portlet handler methods in order to email information about them? I know I could do try catching on every handler method but it would be a much more elegant and cleaner solution to catch the exception on a higher level and just email some information about the error.

I'm using Spring Portlet MVC, so i got all spring-related niceties at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem(s) solved.

Made a class that **implements org.springframework.web.portlet.HandlerExceptionResolver** and declared it in **applicationContext.xml**:

```
<bean id="myExeptionResolver" class="net.foo.bar.MyExeptionResolver" />
```

Spring picks the class up and magically knows what it's for.

For the emailing I used Liferay's MailEngine.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [maven archetype](https://liferayblog.appspot.com/blog/liferay-spring-plugin-with-unit-testing-support) for spring based portlet. There is an implementation of exception resolver that emails an administrator based on level of priority.